# How to avoid restarting server after Deploying on API-M WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to deploy a new API on API-M.

And every time I deploy a new API I must restart the WSO2 application using cmd.

So could anyone help me to resolve this issue? I want to deploy direct without restarting jdk or java or something like this.

Comment: whats the APIM version?

Comment: @RrR- version 4.0

Comment: Do you have a distributed environment setup or are you using a Single API Manager server in your environment? And when you create and publish an API from the Publisher portal, are you seeing any errors in the wso2carbon logs? Why you had to restart the API Manager in the first place, Are your APIs failing to be invoked?

Comment: @Athiththan there is no error in the logs it's just need to restart the jdk after any new deployment

Comment: Can you also share the other information I have requested above?

Comment: @Athiththan Yes I have distributed environment , No there is no error when I publish the API on publisher .

Comment: @Athiththan Are your APIs failing to be invoked? there is only one message says that the API not found

Comment: How the environment is distributed? Can you please share that information as well? How many nodes and how they have been profiled? My suspect is that when the API is published the Gateway node is not updated with the event saying that there have been an API published and to load them. Please share the requested information to check further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the same problem intermitently on a distributed deployement with the gateway separated from the control plane.

The config was ok because sometimes the gateway was notified and sometimes not.

To observe the notification sent to the gateway you can activate the logs as described here by Lakshita.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75810264/18360367

If you never see jms message, this is a configuration issue. If you see these messages, it could be a network issue.